# accessing specific key value via flask pymongo Object

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymongo, flask-mongoengine, pymongo-2.x

lets say

```
db = MongoEngine(app)

class User(db.Document):
    uid = db.SequenceField()
    uname = db.StringField()    

user = User.objects
```

I dont know much mongodb, but is something like this possible?:

```
specific_user = user[uid]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, but here you go:

```
specific_user = user.find_one({"uid": uid})
```

You can read more about querying objects in Pymongo [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#querying-by-objectid)